# Inserting data in mongo collection through cmd command

Tags: mongodb, cmd

When I am inserting data in MongoDb database using cmd command

mongo mongodb://localhost:27017/DummyDatabase --eval "db.Dummy.insert({a:12345,b:asd})"

I am getting following error -

> MongoDB shell version v4.2.0
>
> connecting to: mongodb://localhost:27017/Ontologies?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
>
> Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("6da84ed8-8bf0-4a6c-9d38-7c70cbfc8c7e") }
>
> MongoDB server version: 4.2.0
> 2019-11-07T13:49:15.316+0530 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: ReferenceError: asd is not defined :
> @(shell eval):1:38
> 2019-11-07T13:49:15.320+0530 E  -        [main] exiting with code -4

But when I give this command  -

mongo mongodb://localhost:27017/DummyDatabase --eval "db.Dummy.insert({a:12345})"

This works, what can be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with failing command is that the value provided to the field with key 'b' is not a legal JSON value type. asd is a string that needs to be enclosed in quotes so that the document being inserted can be a valid JSON object. Refer to [json.org](https://json.org) for details.

Comment: With enclosing it with double quotes also it gives uncaught exception: ReferenceError: asd is not defined :

Comment: Ensure that asd is enclosed in quotes. So the command will look like this.

mongo mongodb://localhost:27017/DummyDatabase --eval "db.Dummy.insert({a:12345,b:"asd"})"

Comment: Oh yes, sorry about that. Turns out that the string needs to be enclosed in single quotes. Try this : mongo mongodb://localhost:27017/DummyDatabase --eval "db.Dummy.insert({a:12345,b:'asd'})"